# Pointer to array of pointers to functions

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

The idea is to call different functions based on their index in table.
But line 27 generates the runtime error ((
I tried to fix but didn't succeed (((
Here's the simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f1 (void) {
  std::cout << "f1" << "\n";
}

void f2 (void) {
  std::cout << "f2" << "\n";
}

typedef void (*fPtr[3])(void); // simple "[]" instead of "[3]" gets the compile error

class modeChanger {
  public:
    modeChanger (fPtr funcArray);
    void op ();
  private:
    fPtr *_funcArray;
};

modeChanger::modeChanger (fPtr funcArray) {
  _funcArray = (fPtr *) funcArray;
}

void modeChanger::op () {
  (*_funcArray[0])();
  (*_funcArray[1])(); // Line 27: this line generates a runtime error! Just comment it to get all work
}

void (*modeFuncArray[])(void) = {f1, f2, f2};

modeChanger *mode = new modeChanger (modeFuncArray);

int main() {
    (*modeFuncArray[1])(); // Works fine

    mode->op(); // generates a runtime error
    return 0;
}
```

This works good:

```
(*_funcArray[0])();
```

as well as this:

```
(*modeFuncArray[1])();
```

but this generates a runtime error...

```
(*_funcArray[1])();
```

Seems that incrementing of _funcArray is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: Firsst thing to do is to not try to shut up compiler warnings by using casts... those warnings are telling you something. (referring to `_funcArray = (fPtr *) funcArray;`)

Comment: May I suggest you stop using raw function pointers in C++? Use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead. That will make much of your code simpler. Then if you use a [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) then you simplify even further. Simple code have less chance of errors or problems.

Comment: Once you've done as M.M says, a read of https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ will be invaluable.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @M.M, almost always when you need to use a C-style cast in C++, you're most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fPtr *_funcArray;` this is the pointer to array, not an array of pointers. You suppressed warnings with help of type casts. See bellow the fixed code.

```
#include <iostream>

void f1 (void) {
  std::cout << "f1" << "\n";
}

void f2 (void) {
  std::cout << "f2" << "\n";
}

typedef void (*fPtr)(void);

class modeChanger {
  public:
    modeChanger (fPtr *funcArray);
    void op ();
  private:
    fPtr *_funcArray;
};

modeChanger::modeChanger (fPtr *funcArray) {
  _funcArray = funcArray;
}

void modeChanger::op () {
  (*_funcArray[0])();
  (*_funcArray[1])(); // Line 27: this line generates a runtime error! Just comment it to get all work
}

void (*modeFuncArray[])(void) = {f1, f2, f2};

modeChanger *mode = new modeChanger (modeFuncArray);

int main() {
    (*modeFuncArray[1])(); // Works fine

    mode->op(); // generates a runtime error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not change the declaration of `modeFuncArray` to use the `fPtr` type instead as well? Like `fPtr modeFuncArray[] = { ... }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is possible too, in this case OP should copy an array. Or OP can left a pointer to array, and then he should dereference a pointer before accessing array elements. All these cases are terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Applying @Someprogrammerdude's advice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <functional>

void f1 (void) {
  std::cout << "f1" << "\n";
}

void f2 (void) {
  std::cout << "f2" << "\n";
}

using fPtr = std::function<void()>;
using fPtrs = std::array<fPtr, 3>;

class modeChanger {
  public:
    modeChanger (fPtrs funcArray);
    void op ();
  private:
    fPtrs _funcArray;
};

modeChanger::modeChanger (fPtrs funcArray) : _funcArray(funcArray) { }

void modeChanger::op () {
  _funcArray[0]();
  _funcArray[1]();
}   

int main() {
    fPtrs modeFuncArray = {f1, f2, f2};
    modeChanger mode(modeFuncArray);
    modeFuncArray[1]();

    mode.op(); 
    return 0;
}
```

And thus instead of "hard to declare" C types, we have things as easy as `int`, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

as you use c++, you should use c++ features and not C, you should use `<functional>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
void f1(void) {
    std::cout << "f1" << "\n";
}

void f2(void) {
    std::cout << "f2" << "\n";
}

typedef void(*fPtr[3])(void); // simple "[]" gets the compile error

class modeChanger {
public:
    modeChanger(std::function<void(void)>* funcArray);
    void op();
private:
    std::function<void(void)> * _funcArray;
};

modeChanger::modeChanger(std::function<void(void)>* funcArray) {
    _funcArray = funcArray;
}

void modeChanger::op() {
    _funcArray[0]();
    _funcArray[1](); // this line generates a runtime error! Just comment it to get all work
}

std::function<void(void)>  modeFuncArray[]  = { f1, f2, f2 };

modeChanger *mode = new modeChanger(modeFuncArray);

int main() {
    modeFuncArray[1](); // Works fine

    mode->op(); // generates a runtime error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a mess IMHO. You say not to "use C features" but your code is full of pointers.

Comment: @M.M i wanted to keep the origin code and format for the OP, so he will see the difference of using it.